# selected SegmentedControl's font separately

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, uisegmentedcontrol

I am developing an iOS app using swift,
and i would like to change the selected SegmentedControl's font, only the selected one, i have found already how to change the font for all the segments but i am looking for a way to do it separately, like for example bold only for the selected segment.

this is how to do it for all segments in UISegmentedControl :

```
let attr = NSDictionary(object: UIFont(name: "OpenSans", size: 12.0)!, forKey: NSFontAttributeName as NSCopying)
UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(attr as [NSObject : AnyObject] , for: .normal)
```

Comment: This is Swift. Do not use `NSDictionary`. And note that `attr` should be `[AnyHashable: Any]`, not `[NSObject: AnyObject]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setTitleTextAttributes` for `UIControlState` just use not `.normal` but `.selected`